# Jquery Save Score

Tags: jquery

How do you make the score update though input

At the moment if you input say 10 it returns 10 and doesn't save the new score.

What i want it to do is, say we play rounds , round 1 , round 2, round 3

var score = 0

> Round 1 : i inputted 5 so my new score is 5 (var score  = 5)
>
> Round 2 : i inputted 10 so my new score should be 15 (var score  = 15)
>
> Round 3 :  i inputted 50 so my new score should be 65 (var score  = 65)

```
  <input id="number_1">
        <span id="counter">Total</span>
        <br>
    <button id="add_score">Add</button>

 <script>   
         var score = 0;
        $('#add_score').click(function(){
            scoreAdd = parseInt($('#number_1').val());
            totalScore = score + scoreAdd;
            $('#counter').html(totalScore);
        });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your line

```
totalScore = score + scoreAdd;
$('#counter').html(totalScore);
```

with the following.

```
score = score + scoreAdd;
$('#counter').html(score);
```

```js
var score = 0;
$('#add_score').click(function() {
  scoreAdd = parseInt($('#number_1').val());
  score = score + scoreAdd;
  $('#counter').html(score);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="number_1">
<span id="counter">Total</span>
<br>
<button id="add_score">Add</button>
```